# I've found this problem on transpositions absolutely intractable.

Tags: combinatorics, monty-hall

A University bike shed contains n cubicles in a row. Each cubicle stores one bicycle.

One morning, Professor Ponte places his bicycle in one of the cubicles. At night Priyanka attempts to steal his bike by opening one and only one
of the cubicles. The next morning Professor Ponte moves his bike from
the cubicle it is currently in to one of the cubicles adjacent to the one
it was in before, and closes the cubicle that Priyanka opened. Note that if the bicycle is in one of the cubicles at the end then there is only one possible cubicle for it to be moved to the follow morning. This repeats
every morning and corresponding night.

Devise a general strategy for Priyanka to successfully steal Professor Ponte’s
bike. Note that your strategy must work for any number n of cubicles in
the bike shed.

This is the statement of the problem that's given and I know it's a bit of slog and even unclear. So I'm assuming it means there is only one bicycle among the n cubicles, namely the Professor's bicycle.

I could solve the problem for the n=4 case but could go no further. For the 4-case, my sequence of cubicle picks is 22332 (number corresponding to the given cubicle) and at some point during this Priyanka would gain the bicycle, e.g. she may gain it at 2, 22 but the maximum length is 22332.

Comment: Hint:  if you knew the bike started in an odd numbered cubicle you could trap it in at most $n$ trials (how?).  If that fails, then it must have started in an even numbered cubicle.

Comment: Thanks so much! I'm gonna spend a while longer thinking about it.

Comment: Ok I think I get it now. So for the odd case you know it's in 1,3,5,7.. giving ceiling(n/2) choices. So for first pick (greedily) go 1, and for each successive pick I'm assuming you haven't got the bike yet. For the next pick as the parity changes you pick from 2,4,6,8.. giving floor(n/2) choices, go 2. Then repeat, but this time you've ruled out 1 so pick from 3,5,7.. ceiling(n/2) -1 choices. Iterating this you can ways get to only one possible choice in at most floor(n/2) + ceiling(n/2) = n picks. QED... and I imagine even case follows symmetrically? Seems so obvious now...

Comment: Can someone please verify if this works? Thanks a lot again!

Comment: https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/455/why-does-this-solution-guarantee-that-the-prince-knocks-on-the-right-door-to-fin/486#486

Comment: Ahh a bijection I see.

Comment: @Indianimperialist123 The idea in your comment is wrong; you are ignoring the fact that the bike can move. The optimal solution takes $2n-4$ picks (I think, I have no proof).

Comment: @Mike Earnest My solution was just for the odd case.. I'm conjecturing it for the even one, and I don't see how it's wrong for the odd case anyway.

Comment: @Indianimperialist123 I apologize, I did not read carefully enough.

Comment: The odd and even cases are similar.  I agree with @MikeEarnest  something like $2n-4$ should be optimal (for the minimum worst case) but I have no thought about proving that.

Comment: Well looks like I'm pulling an all nighter on this problem then.

Comment: Were you asked to find the optimal solution?  That doesn't appear in your post.

Comment: Nope! Just that one exists, but I like to (attempt to) generalise.